Access Azure Devops Query Results Using C#
I've fairly new to C# and have no experience of making API calls using it. I'm also a complete beginner to Azure Devops having only recently started interacting with it through work.
I have developed a console application in C# which does some ETL work on CSV files. Currently I have to manually download these CSVs from various Azure Devops projects by using the "Export to CSV" option on query results (see screenshot)

Is there  way I can just connect to the results of this query through C# rather than having to manually download them before running the app?
I thought at first there would be a way of accessing the results by connecting to the Azure devops project through visual studio, but when I connect to that, I no longer have my application solution open.
I did a bit of googling and found that the following Nuget packages may help:
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client

But I can find no useful documentation that tells me how to use these. I know there is an Azure Devops REST API I could use, but I have no idea how to use it with C# and can't find any helpful articles.
I have created a personal access token on Azure Devops but don't know how to use this in Visual Studio.
Maybe it's just the fact that my lack of experience and knowledge means I'm not using the correct search text in google, but I'm completely stumped.
The only articles I found were Microsoft Learn articles with specific examples, which I have never found helpful as they assume a high level of knowledge already, which I do not have.
I'm not looking for a ready written solution, but just after some guidance and/or some links that explain how to achieve my goal. Maybe some tutorials I can follow, as I would like to learn how to do this myself instead of simply plugging in a working solution that I am unable to troubleshoot myself.
Apologies in advance if my question is unclear and for any assistance.
Cheers
Steve

There's two ways to make Web API calls to Azure DevOps. You can make REST API requests with whatever web client you want (HttpClient), or you use Microsoft's C# library which, in my opinion, is horribly documented. I understand you're new to this, but it would be better to start small. Instead of jumping right to getting the data you...

...ultimately want, try something simple, like fetching a list of Projects in your org/collection. That way you know authentication and networking work. THEN you can try to figure out how to get the data you really want. It also wouldn't hurt to open your browser's networking tools to inspect the HTTP request made when you click the export button - that can give you a good hint about what to do in C#. Granted, it might be an undocumented API call.

Also, why does it matter trying to reproduce that button specifically? You can run a WIQL query yourself in C# (either a saved query by its ID or an ad-hoc statement) and get the raw data back. Then you can generate the CSV file yourself, or output it in any other format.

Thanks @gunr2171 I have started small & have an app which returns the projectID from a given project name. So I've got the connection working. I'm now looking at executing WIQL. One thing I've found so far is that executing the WIQL query DOES NOT return the columns specified in the query, which is a little odd. When I step through the code I found, and look at the value of the variable that contains the text of the WIQL query, all the fields are there. But when I try to print their values to the console, I'm being told certain fields are not in the dictionary. More investigation needed.

I have found the reason for these field omissions. It would appear that if no data appears in a column, the field will not be added to the dictionary list. Have to say that is just plain stupid as work items have various stages in their investigation and won't always have all the all the fields filled in.

I got around this by it by creating a string list of the fields I want and checking for each string in the dictionary list of fields and returning "" if it isn't present.

OK, so I found some code which I have slightly altered to work how I need it.
This is the code I used to establish a connection using a persoanl access token, which I am reading in from an embedded resource file.
static void ConnectWithPAT(string ServiceURL, string PAT)
{
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
    InitClients(connection);
}

The InitClients method is as follows (I didn't touch this bit):
static void InitClients(VssConnection Connection)
{
    WitClient = Connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
    BuildClient = Connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
    ProjectClient = Connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
    GitClient = Connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
    TfvsClient = Connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
    TestManagementClient = Connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
}

Then there's a method that executes the WIQL code:
static void RunStoredQuery(string project, string queryPath)
{
    QueryHierarchyItem query = WitClient.GetQueryAsync(project, queryPath, QueryExpand.Wiql).Result;

    string wiqlStr = query.Wiql;

    GetQueryResult(wiqlStr, project);
}

The GetQueryResult method calls another method called RunQueryByWiql - WorkItemQueryResult result = RunQueryByWiql(wiqlStr, teamProject);
static WorkItemQueryResult RunQueryByWiql(string wiqlStr, string teamProject)
{
    Wiql wiql = new Wiql();
    wiql.Query = wiqlStr;

    if (teamProject == "") return WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;
    else return WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql, teamProject).Result;
}

I then just use a StreamWriter to write the results out to a CSV file.
Many thanks @gunr2171 for the guidance. I got there in the end.
Cheers
Steve
